# Why screen SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW enable cancel button and disable install button when apk install?

Tags: android

Please help and clarify me, why screen `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` enable cancel button and disable install button when apk install??

```
windowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                    0 | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

This is my code in `Activity`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called tap-jacking protection, and is designed to prevent misleading the user into thinking the install button was something else (for example, by overlaying the bottom bar and switching the labels around), and passing the click through.

Comment: how to enable install button??

Comment: You can't. If you display any overlay, the install button will never be clickable. If you could work around that, it wouldn't be much of a security feature now would it...